# Capture image not working android phone

Tags: android

I am working of image capture by camera. 
I start intent to capture image. but after capturing 2 3 time camera capture not work and file created is of length 0.
Below is my code which i am using for this task.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        capturePhotoForRecordUpload();
        }


 public synchronized void capturePhotoForRecordUpload() {

        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createFileForNewRecordImage();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
                Debug.printException(ex);
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 100);
            }
        }
    }



     @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        String errorString = "";


        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                //startLoading();
                mCurrentPhotoPath = Common.getSharedPreference(CaptureRecordActivity.this, "mCurrentPhotoPath");
                if(new File(mCurrentPhotoPath).exists() && new File(mCurrentPhotoPath).length() > 0){
                 // here i upload the record

            }else{
                errorString = "Error while uploading file. Please try again.";
            }

        }else{

        }

        /// display the toast  of errorString here 

       }

        private  File createFileForNewRecordImage() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = new File(Common.getTempUploadDirectoryPath());
        if(!storageDir.exists())
            storageDir.mkdirs();
        if(!storageDir.exists())
            storageDir.mkdir();

    // I also checked this by removing the below lines
       /* File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );*/

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        Common.updateSharedPreference(this, "mCurrentPhotoPath", mCurrentPhotoPath);
        return image;
    }
```

Comment: its because your uri is wrong, check if folder is created first

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I solved it. I was my mistake while capture photo by camera my activity is getting killed. And I was creating the file name using the system time in oncreate().As my activity is getting kill it again call all life cycle of activity and my destination file name is getting change. so I made changes in file names creation and solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

The EXTRA_OUTPUT is not a file.  It needs to be a content provider URI.  I can't tell from your code where its being stored, but it definitely could not be in your app's private directory-  the other intent wouldn't have write permission there.  Unless you want to implement a full content provider for this, do not pass it an output URI and let it choose a filename.  Or see http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html for example code.  Yours is more than a bit clunky.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I solved it. I was my mistake while capture photo by camera my activity is getting killed. And I was creating the file name using the system time in oncreate().As my activity is getting kill it again call all life cycle of activity and my destination file name is getting change. so I made changes in file names creation and solved my problem